# Exponential form of a log

Tags: exponential-function

I'm a bit confused on the wording of this question:

An equation is shown below

x = log(20)

What is the exponential form of this equation?

So my answer is $10^x$=20. But I am not sure if that is even the right format of an exponential form or if that is the most simplified answer I can give?

Comment: Yes, it means taking $\exp$ on both sides: $\exp(x)=\exp(\log(20))$. More generally, $a^x=a^{\log(20)}$ for base $a$.

Comment: If by $x = \log 20$, you mean $x = \log_{10} 20$, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $e^{x}$ is the inverse function of $\ln(x)$, so they "undo" each other: $e^{\ln(x)}=x$ and $\ln(e^x)=x$. Therefore you can rearrange your equation by doing this:

\begin{equation}
e^x = e^{\ln20} \\
\therefore e^x = 20
\end{equation}

which is the "exponential form" of the equation.